# installing .Net dotnet on debian

Tags: debian, terminal, .net, visual-studio-code

I downloaded ./dotnet-install.sh  and successfully installed:

```
$ ./dotnet-install.sh -c Current
dotnet-install: Note that the intended use of this script is for Continuous Integration (CI) scenarios, where:
dotnet-install: - The SDK needs to be installed without user interaction and without admin rights.
dotnet-install: - The SDK installation doesn't need to persist across multiple CI runs.
dotnet-install: To set up a development environment or to run apps, use installers rather than this script. Visit https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download to get the installer.

dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK version 5.0.207 is already installed.
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/home/tesla/.dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
dotnet-install: Note that the script does not resolve dependencies during installation.
dotnet-install: To check the list of dependencies, go to https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install, select your operating system and check the "Dependencies" section.
dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.
```

I added path

└─$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/tesla/.dotnet

dotnet --version
5.0.207

I have two issues:

First, everytime I restart the PC, I need to reinstall
Second vs code terminal does not see dotnet --version command:

```
"Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk   # version 5.0.401, or
sudo apt  install dotnet-host
See 'snap info dotnet-sdk' for additional versions. "
```

If I set the path on vscode terminal, after re staring the vscode, it does not recognize dotnet command

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your PATH to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file.

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/tesla/.dotnet
```

To update the changes immediately

```
source ~/.profile 
or
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install dotnet :

1- By installing the tarball:

```
wget https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/5.0.207/dotnet-sdk-5.0.207-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet
sudo tar -zxf dotnet-sdk-5.0.207-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

2- By installing the .deb file

You can download the `.deb` file [from here](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/), e,g:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```